# Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread when schema is updated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I tried to implement dynamic database routing steps to my application.
Everything works fine when "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" is none.

When I want to update my database scheme I change "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" to "update", and I get this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.preferredDatabaseSession': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
>       at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]

I try to create my own RequestContextHolder, but it didn't work. I have a session scope bean, I guess I missed something.

My session scope class:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class PreferredDatabaseSession implements Serializable {

private DatabaseEnvironment preferredDb;

public DatabaseEnvironment getPreferredDb() {
    return preferredDb;
}

public void setPreferredDb(DatabaseEnvironment preferredDb) {
    this.preferredDb = preferredDb;
}

}
```

I call it like:

```
public class DataSourceRouter extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Autowired
    private PreferredDatabaseSession db;

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
    return db.getPreferredDb();
    }
}
```

Also call from here:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private PreferredDatabaseSession userDatabaseSession;

private void setPreferredDatabase() throws DataAccessException {
    // String preferredDb = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("preferredDb");
    String preferredDb = request.getParameter("preferredDb");
    if (preferredDb.equals(Constants.JPLATFORM)) {
        userDatabaseSession.setPreferredDb(DatabaseEnvironment.JPLATFORM);
    } else if (preferredDb.equals(Constants.TIGER)) {
        userDatabaseSession.setPreferredDb(DatabaseEnvironment.TIGER);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: why are you using session scope onPreferredDatabaseSession?

Comment: @slimane because i want users select database at login page. Until they logout and select another database they should use same database after selection.

Comment: I see, can you post any relevant code snippet where you are trying to access HTTP request information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserDetailsServiceImpl is a singleton bean but HttpServletRequest is a request scoped bean, that's what the exception is about.

try to use

```
ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    HttpServletRequest request = requestAttributes.getRequest();
```

instead of autowiring the HttpServletRequest

also fall to a default datasource when routing:

```
@Override
protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() == null) {
    return DEFAULT_ONE;
}
return db.getPreferredDb();
}
```

Comment: When hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is none it works fine. But when i change it to "update" it gives error. Maybe this can be a hint.

Comment: when hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update, do you get the exception at the startup of your app?

Comment: When it is "update" i got errors at the startup. i write these errors on main question body. But when it is "none" everything works fine.

Comment: yeah, that's the point, the problem is PreferredDatabaseSession is session scoped which means the bean only exists when a web request comes.when hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update at the startup there is no request so the PreferredDatabaseSession  bean won't be available in the context thus the exception will be thrown from DataSourceRouter

Comment: thank you. So do you have any idea how to solve this problem? PreferredDatabaseSession must be a session scope and also i need to update my schema :) I try many things like creating RequestContextListener but nothing solved this problem.

Comment: now; works like a charm :) Thank you @slimane you just saved all day :)

Comment: OMG so easy for a problem so annoying. Thank you!